# Is the Scala Breeze package thread safe for use in Spark Dataframe processing?

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, scala-breeze

Does the use of ThreadLocal for singleton variables make them thread safe for use in Spark Dataframe processing framework?  The Breeze fourierTr functions use ThreadLocal and it seems to cause problems for me.

I am building an application to assemble multi-dimensional tables and compute an FFT on various dimensions.

```
val r = df.rdd.flatMap{ row =>
      // scrub the input, format data into coordinates with a value
      // create a key corresponding to a slice through the data
      // that will get processed in the next step      
    }
    .groupByKey.flatMap{ case( sliceKey, coordinateList ) => 
      // note the vector length is variable
      val buf = new Array[Complex]( lengthOfVector )
      // fill buffer with values from data structure slice
      fourierTr( new DenseVector(buf) )
    }
```

Note, this is just pseudo code.  I've cut out much of the real code to make a concise example.

The key point is the call for fourierTr.  When I ran this on my local development machine everything was fine, and I got the expected result.  However, when I moved to a bigger, multi-core machine I got the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 10.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 36, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
    at edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D.passfg(DoubleFFT_1D.java:3843)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D.cfftf(DoubleFFT_1D.java:3390)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D.complexForward(DoubleFFT_1D.java:189)
    at edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D.complexForward(DoubleFFT_1D.java:161)
    at breeze.signal.fourierTr$$anon$5.apply(fourierTr.scala:69)
    at breeze.signal.fourierTr$$anon$5.apply(fourierTr.scala:62)
    at breeze.generic.UFunc$class.apply(UFunc.scala:48)
    at breeze.signal.fourierTr$.apply(fourierTr.scala:25)
```

At first I thought this may be due to a package versioning difference between my development machine and the cluster (ie. using AWS).  After making sure all the relevant jar versions were matching I still had the same problem.  Then I determined that the application ran fine if I launched it with

```
spark-submit --master local[1] ...
```

However, if I launched it with

```
spark-submit --master local[2] ...
```

or any node count higher than 2 then I would get the exception.  Which made me suspect that some memory was getting corrupted somehow.  So I started digging into the library source.

The entry point is in [fourierTr.scala](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/master/math/src/main/scala/breeze/signal/fourierTr.scala)

```
  implicit val dvComplex1DFFT : fourierTr.Impl[DenseVector[Complex], DenseVector[Complex]] = {
    new fourierTr.Impl[DenseVector[Complex], DenseVector[Complex]] {
      def apply(v: DenseVector[Complex]) = {
        //reformat for input: note difference in format for input to real fft
        val tempArr = denseVectorCToTemp(v)

        //actual action
        val fft_instance = getD1DInstance(v.length)
        fft_instance.complexForward( tempArr ) //does operation in place

        //reformat for output
        tempToDenseVector(tempArr)
      }
    }
  }
```

Pushing in to getD1DInstance in [JTransformsSupport.scala](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/master/math/src/main/scala/breeze/signal/support/JTransformsSupport.scala) I find ...

```
object JTransformsSupport {

  //maintain instance of transform to eliminate repeated initialization
  private val fft_instD1D = new ThreadLocal[(Int, DoubleFFT_1D)]

  def getD1DInstance(length: Int): DoubleFFT_1D = {
    if (fft_instD1D.get != null && length == fft_instD1D.get._1) fft_instD1D.get._2
    else {
      fft_instD1D.set((length, new DoubleFFT_1D(length)))
      fft_instD1D.get()._2
    }
  }
```

Note that it is modifying a shared variable fft_instD1D.  I'm not very familiar with the ThreadLocal type, but it seems this is intended to make the class thread safe.  However, I changed my code to instantiate a DoubleFFT_1D object as a stack variable, then I called all the low level routines directly (eg. rather than call fourierTr I called DoubleFFT_1D.complexForward).

After making this change the exception no longer occurred regardless of the number of nodes used by Spark.  So it seems like the use of ThreadLocal by the Fourier transform library was the culprit.

I would like to know if others who would consider themselves experts in Scala/Breeze/Spark agree with my conclusion?

If it is not correct, please suggest how to use Breeze (specifically fourierTr) properly in the context of Spark Dataframe processing.

If it is the correct conclusion, then I have some follow up questions...

1. Was I wrong to assume that Breeze functions can be called from within
   the Dataframe processing pipeline?  If Breeze is not intended to be called from the Dataframe processing pipeline, then is there a standard way to wrap a library so that it can be called from the pipeline, or is it generally necessary to do what I did and rewrite part of the library functionality to eliminate the shared variable?
2. If Breeze is intended to be called from the Dataframe pipeline, then
   does this look like a bug in the Breeze library, or in the
   implementation of the ThreadLocal class? ... ie. whose attention
   should I bring this to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please file a bug with Breeze: github.com/scalanlp/breeze/issues

Breeze strives to be threadsafe (that's why we use ThreadLocal to have one instance of the transform per thread), but something went wrong here. (That ThreadLocal code looks totally fine to me, but then again I wrote it.)

Comment: thanks for the quick rely.  I will file this with Breeze: github.com/scalanlp/breeze/issues as you suggest.